# JAXB - How can I return a List of Objects (List<Object>)

Tags: java, xml, exception, jaxb

I've got a problem:

I need a `List` of different objects, to guarantee the correct processing.

In the XML File, I need a specific order of the Elements. The standard of `JAXB` is that the Elements are ordered alphabetically, but I need them in the order they were added like.

For this I wrote much Functions, and now, as the Output, I have a `List<Object>` which I wanted to return to `JAXB` and marshall it with the `@XmlAnyElement` Tag.

```
@XmlAnyElement
private List<Object> getJAXBElements() {
    return list;
}
```

The Objects are generated from different classes in different packages. Now, as the result, I'm getting this exception from `JAXB`:

> [com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: Weder class
>   objects.xml.adminlanguage.XMLAdminLanguage noch eine der zugehörigen
>   Superklassen ist diesem Kontext bekannt.
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(Unknown
>   Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown
>   Source)
>       at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)

Does anybody know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: The Exception is only telling you that the class ``XMLAdminLanguage`` is not known in that JAXBContext. Try adding it to the context.

Comment: Thank you, I've added the JAXB Context via @XmlSeeAlso({ClassName1.class,ClassName2.class,...})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem:

I've added the JAXB Context via `@XmlSeeAlso({ClassName1.class,ClassName2.class,...})`

You can also read it at [Red Hat JBoss Fuse - @XmlSeeAlso Tag](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Developing_Applications_Using_JAX-WS/files/JAXWSDataMappingOverMoreClasses.html)